# AirWatch Agent launching when app is run

Tags: ios, airwatch

Every time I launch my iOS app on iOS device that has been downloaded through my company's internal AirWatch App Store, the AirWatch Agent launches. This forces me to have to click "Back to App" in the top left corner to get out of the Agent. My hunch is that it has something to do with the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the Info.plist. The first problem with this is that I strictly followed the AirWatch iOS SDK documentation when entering those values. The second problem with that is I have another app I developed with those same values that does not launch the AirWatch Agent app run. Very frustrating! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you launch the app : AirWatch SDK launches the Agent to get the app configuration payload from your MDM server.
Once the payload is on your device, the app should never start the Agent again.
You should check the process with your MDM admin...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the agent (after verifying/authenticating your app or whatever) to jump back to your app again.

We too had this unwanted behavior, you'll need to set the callback scheme in the sdk handling, like explained [here](https://kb.air-watch.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001676468-AirWatch-iOS-SDK-implementation-walkthrough?mobile_site=true). At least that fixed it for us.